# Java won't accept parameter of Map<String, MyClass> when the method signature is Map<String, IMyInterface> and MyClass implements IMyInterface

Tags: java, generics

I am getting the error:

`Error:(6356, 38) java: incompatible types: java.util.Map<java.lang.String,net.windward.format.wordml.WordMLParser.WordMLControl> cannot be converted to java.util.Map<java.lang.String,net.windward.format.OfficeMLParserBase.IOfficeXmlControl>`

Where the class I am passing is:

```
private abstract static class WordMLControl implements IOfficeXmlControl {
    ...
}
```

And the method is:

```
protected void setProcessControl(Map<String, IOfficeXmlControl> procs) {
    ...
}
```

Why is this an error - I think this should be fine as the objects implement that interface.

**Update:** Ok, I understand this issue now (thank you Jorn). But the question remains, what's a good solution for this? In my case I will always get either `Map<Cat>` or `Map<Dog>` and that map is only read from.

Comment: @JornVernee - it looks like even generics won't get me around this. Good explination on the link you provided, but no good solution to this problem that I saw.

Comment: If you strictly want to take values out of the map, you could use: `Map<String, ? extends IOfficeXmlControl>` as a parameter type (i.e. [PECS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397)). That will allow you to pass a `Map<String, WordMLControl>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you declare a method

```
protected void setProcessControl(Map<String, IOfficeXmlControl> procs)
```

the passed parameter can only be a `Map<String, IOfficeXmlControl>`. If you want allow all implementing classes, you have to change the declaration to

```
protected void setProcessControl(Map<String, ? extends IOfficeXmlControl> procs)
```

If that's not an option, you can do a bad hack when you pass your map to the method:

```
setProcessControl((Map<String, IOfficeXmlControl>) (Map) myMap);
```

Instead of an error you get a compiler warning but the call should work.

Comment: The "? extends" was what I needed - thank you